# Android: onActivityResult is not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am having a problem with my code and i don't know what's the reason behind it. Am trying to update a textview in the main activity from second activity. I tried to make my textview public static but couldn't update it. Also i tried to use intent with onActivityResult method but no result. Here's my main activity java code

```
.....
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String income = data.getStringExtra("X");
                TextView tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MainIncome);
                tvView.setText(income);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Income Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cant Add Income, Something Went Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
      }
....
```

This is the XML file

```
....
    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Current Income: " />

     <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/MainIncome"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0" />
....
```

and here's my second activity java code

```
    ....
  public void Add_Income(View v) {
        EditText IncomePayee = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IncomePayee);
        EditText IncomeAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IncomeAmount);

        IPayee = IncomePayee.getText().toString();
        IAmount = Double.parseDouble(IncomeAmount.getText().toString());

        IAmount += GlobalVariables.TotIncome;

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("X", Double.toString(IAmount));
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
  }
....
```

Here's the XML file

```
....
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="Income Amount"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/IncomePayee"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/AddIncomeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="Add_Income"
        android:text="Add Income" />
....
```

One last note. Am not sure if using intent is the proper way to change the text view or not since i do have more than one activity can be lunched from the main activity.

Comment: your way of achieving that is really idk, just weird && also "I tried to make my textview public static" no, rather the string..

Comment: When calling an activity with startActivityForResult make sure you don't call finish .

Answer (score 0):

Did you call [startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) or you using just [startActivity (Intent intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) when starting new activity? For receive result, you should call startActivityForResult method.

Comment: I did used "startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)" to lunch each activity in the project (around 5 activities in total)

Answer (score 0):

first of all:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("X", Double.toString(IAmount));
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

define the intent:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),toActivity.class);
```

and then

```
    startActivityForResult(intent);
```

after this when you come back from the activity your onActivityResult() code will run.

Answer (score -1):

In your intent you din't specified which class it should go.

In your Add_Income method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, <Put your destination class>.class);
intent.putExtra("X", Double.toString(IAmount));
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: I tried to specify it but unfortunately still not working. Thank you for your tries and time.

Comment: does your second activity display any layout?
I mean did it extends activity?
If no then you I think i can help

Comment: Too bad then, because my second activity contains different elements and yes it display layout. appreciate your help Thank you once again.